# How do I prove that 15462227 and 15462229 relatively prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Are 15,462,227 and 15,462,229 relatively prime?

How do I construct a proof for this.

I know that for n and n+2 to be relatively prime it is the case that n has to be odd. Is this the only requirement for these numbers to be relatively prime?

Comment: If $a:=15462229$, $b:=15462227$, we have $gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,a-b)=gcd(a,2)=1$ because $a$ is odd. That's all!

Comment: $\ (a,a+2) = (a,2)\ $ by the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b-a)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $15,462,229$ and $15,462,227$ have a common divisor $d$ they can be written as $q_1d$ and $q_2 d$, and so is their difference $(q_1-q_2)d = 2$, so $d$ is also a divisor of $2$ thus either $2$ or $1$, which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the GCD by Euclid's algorithm!  The GCD of n and n+2 is the GCD of 2 and n, which is 1 if n is odd.

Answer (score 0):

In general the way to answer this question is the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). In this case it's very simple (one step):

$$
15,462,229 = 15,462,227 + 2 
$$

so the greatest common divisor of the two numbers in question is the same as the greatest common divisor of either and $2$. That's clearly $1$.