# Find gcd(15570555, 10872579)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

How do I find this?

I know that I should use perhaps:

$gcd(a,b) = gcd(a,a-b) $

But then I get:

$gcd(15570555,4697976) $

Which seems still too large for me to do anything further.

Comment: Keep going.  But maybe use some common sense as well. 5 obviously divides one but not the other and as 5 is prime it would be a common factor so we can divide it out.

Comment: Maybe if you use $a=bk+r$ then $(a,b)=(b,r)$.

Comment: I seem to recall the Euclidean algorithm, i.e. long division, is of use here. Have you tried it?

Comment: Almost duplicate of the very recent question (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1998324) where it has been abundantly said that the key is Euclidean algorithm. Do you belong to the same class ?

Answer (score 2):

You  did one step.  Keep going.

$1557055 - 10872579 = 4697976$ so $\gcd(1557055,10872579) = \gcd(10872579,4697976)$

$10872579-2*4697976 = 1476627$ so $\gcd(10872579,4697976)= \gcd(4697976,1476627)$

and so on..

$4697976 - 3*1476627 = 268095$

$1476627 -5*268095=136152$

$268095 - 136152=131943$

$136152 - 131943= 4209$

$131943-31*4209 =1464$

$4209 - 2*1464=1281$

$1464 - 1281 = 183$

$1281 - 7*183 = 0$

So $\gcd(1557055,10872579)= 183$

==== earlier answer in which in order to make it easier, I probably made it harder ======

If $p$ is prime and $p \not \mid c$ but $p |b$ then $\gcd(b,c) = \gcd(b/p,c)$ as $p$ will not be a common factor. And if $m|c$ and $m|b$ then $\gcd(b,c) = m \gcd(b/m,c/m)$.

So $15570555 = 5*3*1038037$

$4697976 = 8*3*195749$ so $\gcd(1557055, 4697976) = 3\gcd(1038037,195749)$.

Using the $11$ division trick of every other digit I see $11|1038037$ $1038037=11*94367$.  But $11 \not \mid 195749$

So $\gcd(1557055, 4697976)=3\gcd(94367,195749)$

We can use euclid's algorithm now.

$195,749 - 2*94,367= 7015$

So $\gcd(94367,195749)=\gcd(94367,7015)$

$94,367 - 13*7015 = 3172$

$7015 - 2*3172 = 671$

$3172 - 4*671 = 488$

$671 - 488 = 183$

$488 - 2*183 = 122$

$183 - 122 = 61$

$122 = 2*61$

so $\gcd(94367,7015)=61$

And $\gcd(1557055, 4697976) = 3*61 = 183$

Comment: I would reword "we can use Euclid's ... now" since it might be misinterpreted as implying that it couldn't be applied without doing the prior steps.

Comment: You know.... I think my attempts at making it easier, just made it harder.  As this is the age of calculators and wolfram I guess I shouldn't avoid large numbers.  But that 5 was just *staring* at me and 3 was easy factor out.

Comment: Sometimes that is true, and other times optimizations prove quite worthwhile. Unfortunately it's not always easy to predict in advance whether or not it is worth exploring optimizations.

Comment: Well, my concern is confusing the person I'm trying to help.  If the idea is to hammer home euclid's algorithm I guess I should hammer it home.  But... if it's too long (as this one is) it seems to me it comes of as some obscure trick and it's really hard to see why it works.  I can imagine a student seeing those long calculations and concluding "1281−7x183=0"  and thinking "um.... so?"

Comment: It's not clear what if any pedagogical value is gained by having students work out such long computations. One can grok the Euclidean algorithm with smaller numbers and only a few steps.

Comment: I guess the idea is after getting the idea to impress them with the power of it.  We found a rather obscure gcd of 2 very large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{gcd}(15570555,4697976)=(15\cdot 1038037,24\cdot 195749)=3(1038037,195749)$$
$$(1038037,195749)=(5\cdot 195749+59292,195749)=(59292,195749)=(4\cdot 14823,195749)$$
But $195749=13\cdot 14823+3050$
$$\text{gcd}(15570555,4697976)=3(14823,195749)=3(14823,13\cdot 14823+3050)=3(14823,3050)=3(14823,50\cdot 61)$$
$$(14823,61)=(243\cdot 61,61)=61$$
$$\text{gcd}(15570555,4697976)=3\cdot 61=183$$

I used repeatedly the properties:

- $(a,b)=(a,b-a)$.
- If $a=bk+r$ then $(a,b)=(b,r)$.
- If $(a,c)=1$ then $(a,bc)=(a,b)$.
- $(ak,bk)=k(a,b)$

Comment: But 3 is a common factor.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use the *Euclidean algorithm*:
$$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b, a\bmod b)$$
($11$ steps). You should find $183$. Further, using the *extended Euclidean algorithm* yields the coefficients of a *Bézout's relation*.